# JButton double click occurred new thread,why is this happened

Tags: java, sockets, jframe

I tried to selection button to execute client or server Layout, but when I click server button , happened action function execute sever in 13 thread , cause the lock layout,

I don't know why the click have execute other thread?

```
/*
 main is thread 1 doing this task,but button action is thread 13 doing this task
*/
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        System.out.println("Thread # " + threadId + " is doing this task");
        new Main().view();
    }

    private void view() {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Server");
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton jButton = new JButton("test");
        jFrame.setLocation(300, 300);

        jPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 300));

        GroupLayout groupLayout=new GroupLayout(jPanel);
        jPanel.setLayout(groupLayout);

        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED,
                         GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton,0,groupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED,
                         GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                );

        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED,
                         GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton,0,groupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED,
                         GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                );

        jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
                System.out.println("Thread # " + threadId + " is doing this task");
            }
        });
        jFrame.add(jPanel);
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setFocusable(true);
        jFrame.setEnabled(true);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You have discovered the EDT (GUI thread)! See [Swing concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your main :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    System.out.println("Thread # " + threadId + " is doing this task");
}
```

The current thread is the initial one, the one that start the application.

In your button :

```
jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
            System.out.println("Thread # " + threadId + " is doing this task");
        }
```

The current thread is the EDT (Event dispatch thread). This is the thread used by Swing to manage its events.

You can find more informations in [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). It would be good to read because there is some "rules" to following when you use `Swing`. Every event (click, update, ...) are done in the EDT. If you do long processing in it, it will freeze the GUI.